# Por que a validação de Input Type Email aceita domínios sem ponto?

Tags: html, html5, email, validação

O input `type[email]` tem como finalidade validar se o campo está sendo preenchido com um e-mail válido.

Porém diversas vezes já passei por questionamento em alguns projetos sobre o por que esse campo aceitar alguns tipos de e-mail que são aparentemente inválidos.

Exemplo:

```css
[type=email]:invalid{
   color:red;
}
[type=email]:valid{
   color: green;
   border-color: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" value="wallace@dominio-sem-ponto-com" />

<input type="email" value="wallace@xx" />

<input type="email" value="wallace@host.com" />

<input type="email" value="wallace" />
```

Se você observar, nenhum dos e-mails cujo domínio estava sem o `".com"` ou `".net"` foi marcado como inválido.

Por que isso acontece?

Por que o e-mail `"wallace@dominio-sem-ponto-com"` foi considerado válido pelo navegador?

Existe algum caso onde seria válido usar um domínio sem o valor depois do ponto (`.com`, `.net`, etc) ?

Comment: Parece que o critério é "tem arroba". Espero que não seja tao simples assim.

Comment: E porque seria inválido sem ponto? Eu posso ter um bacco@localhost, qual o problema nisso? Email não tem nada a ver com internet.

Comment: @Bacco explica isso para os clientes :p.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters o melhor validador de email é mandar um token pro cara. Se ele recebeu, é válido.

Comment: O sinal "@", arroba, signifca "at", ou "em". É um delimitador para o usuário@dominio. E o domínio pode existir sem o ".com" por exemplo! Você precisa verificar o e-mail, não há outra forma de valida-lo com eficiência.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

a validação ocorre apenas por conta do @, domínio na verdade é um nome, ex: **tassio@dominio**, não necessariamente precisaria ser um sub domínio (com ponto), ex: **tassio@meudominio.com**, em que situações isso podem ocorrer? Dentro de uma intranet por exemplo, ou caso o registro.br ou outros orgãos de registro liberem o registro de domínios primários ai por exemplo poderia registrar  um domínio "`google`", para acessar o site utilizaria apenas `http://google` e um exemplo de e-mail seria `contato@google`.

Answer (score 7):

Segundo a [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp):

> The `<input type="email">` is used for input fields that should contain
>   an e-mail address.
>
> Depending on browser support, the e-mail address can be automatically
>   validated when submitted.
>
> Some smartphones recognize the email type, and adds ".com" to the
>   keyboard to match email input.

Ou seja, esse campo é utilizado campos de entradas que devem conter um endereço de e-mail e dependendo do suporte do navegador, o endereço de e-mail pode ser validado automaticamente quando enviado.

Alguns smartphones reconhecem o tipo de e-mail e acrescentam ".com" ao teclado para corresponder à entrada de e-mail.

**Por que o e-mail "`wallace@dominio-sem-ponto-com`" foi considerado válido pelo navegador?**

Porque na validação de e-mail utilizando o `input type="email"`, o valor deve começar com uma letra ou um número, seguido pelo símbolo `@`, em seguida, terminar com um nome de domínio.

Se você quiser criar a sua própria regra de validação, basta utilizar o atributo
 `pattern`, ele nos permite definir nossa própria regra para validar o valor de entrada usando Expressões Regulares (RegEx). Se o valor não corresponder ao padrão especificado, a entrada irá lançar um erro.

Caso queira que o formulário só aceite nome@email.com, pode usar da seguinte forma:

```
<input type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$" />
```

Curiosidade: Nesse site você pode testar as [validações](http://inputtypes.com/) com input.

Answer (score 2):

Isso ocorre pois o `input` de `type="email"` aceita qualquer texto digitado dentro de si com a única condição de possuir `[email]@[domínio]` em seu valor. Para contornar isso e ter uma melhor validação por lado do cliente utilizador do site, é recomendado utilizar o atributo `pattern=''` que define um padrão para o valor daquele `input` ser aceito, mas cuidado, do lado do cliente, o mesmo pode realizar alterações pelo console para validar o formulário, então é sempre recomendado fazer uma validação no lado do servidor também.

Algo útil a se procurar é a validação de formulários com `RegEx`, que são as expressões regulares passadas dentro do atributo `pattern`, para facilitar a criação dos padrões citados acima.

Um bom site para aprender `RegEx` é o http://regexr.com/ .Clique em references para ver quais são as formas e as expressões usadas para a validação em `html5`

Answer (score 2):

Em complemento:

> Existe algum caso onde seria válido usar um domínio sem o valor depois do ponto (.com, .net, etc) ?

Sim. Devemos lembrar que em hosts locais (como localhost por exemplo) seria totalmente válido a existência de emails como `wallace@localhost`. Isso não significa que o e-mail seja inválido, mas sim que ele não é um e-mail comum "da internet".

Em sistemas de intranet, por exemplo, pode ser comum o uso de e-mails que não contenha domínios convencionais como estamos acostumado.